# Create constants visible across packages, accessible directly

Tags: go

I would like to define my `Error Codes` in a package `models`.

**error.go**

```
package models

const{
  EOK = iota
  EFAILED
}
```

How can I use them in another package without referring to them as `models.EOK`. I would like to use directly as EOK, since these codes would be common across all packages.

Is it the right way to do it? Any better alternatives?

Comment: What is the problem with using packageName.ErrorName, e.g. `models.EOK`? That name will be the same in all uses, everywhere in your program. Maybe put the errors in their own package called, maybe called err to make it shorter and easier to remember?

Comment: not a issue but it would save unnecessary bloating the code by having `models`, was wondering if this is possbile in Go or is there a general coding pattern followed to generate errors?

Comment: As flexy answered you can "dot" import all exported names to your file.  But, it's not a great habit to get in to.  I appreciate the desire to reduce code bloat, but always remember to balance that with readability.  A naked "EOK" in the codebase may leave the next developer reading your code to wonder where it comes from, where "models.EOK" obviously comes from the models package.

Comment: @DavidBudworth: correct.

Comment: @lionelmessi I've added some reads for you to my answers, related to golang error handling style and package/code organisation

Comment: good question. on the same task

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### To answer you core question

You can use the `dot` import syntax to import the exported symbols from another package directly into your package's namespace ([godoc](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)):

```
import . "models"
```

This way you could directly refer to the `EOK` constant without prefixing it with `models`.

**However I'd strongly advice against doing so, as it generates rather unreadable code.** see below

### General/style advice

1. Don't use unprefixed export path like `models`. This is considered bad style as it will easily globber. Even for small projects, that are used only internally, use something like `myname/models`. see [goblog](https://blog.golang.org/organizing-go-code)
2. Regarding your question about *error generation*, there are functions for generating `error` values, e.g. `errors.New` ([godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#New)) and `fmt.Errorf` ([godoc](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Errorf)).
   For a general introduction on go and error handling see [goblog](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values)

Answer (score 1):

W.r.t. the initial question, use a compact package name, for example err.

Choosing an approach to propagating errors, and generating error messages depends on the scale and complexity of the application. The error style you show, using an int, and then a function to decode it, is quite C-ish.

That style was partly caused by:

- the lack of multiple value returns (unlike Go),
- the need to use a simple type (to be easily propagated), and
- that gets translated to text with a function (unlike Go's error interface), so that the local language strings can be changed.

For small apps with simple errors strings. I put the packages' error strings at the head of a package file, and just return them, maybe using errors.New(...), or fmt.Errorf if the string needs to be completed using some data.

That 'int' style of error reporting doesn't offer something as flexible as Go's error interface. The error interface lets us build information-rich error structures, to return useful information, and not just an int value or string.

An implication is *different packages* can yield *different real-types* which implement the Error interface. We don't need to agree a single error real-type across an entire set of packages. So error is an interface which can be easily propagated, like an int, yet, the real-type of error can be much richer than an int. Error generation (implementing Error) can be as centralised or distributed as we need, unlike strerror()-style functions which can be awkward to extend.

Comment: Looks like you caught me from where I am coming from :) I will explore more on this topic!